# How to remove Excalibur from the car?

Tags: remote-start

I have one of these installed on my cheap (at the time) $6k used car.

This car frequently loses it's battery charge, and I am lead to believe it is because this said attached device.

Thanks to my wife being eh, not as delicate with technical things as myself, she has removed the receiver which lights up blue (I didn't think it was attached with a mofset. I thought it to be hardwired).

But that said I am now unable to locate the rest of the device.  I followed the wire and it just disappears into the top of the windshield.

I don't know what I am looking for on the other end, but my neighbor says it should be somewhere in the engine compartment connected to the battery (and I would imagine the starter).

I have no need for a remote starter, and I certainly have no need to charge my battery everytime I drive home.

Can someone please tell me how to remove Excalibur from the stone that is my $6k car?

[image: Omega Excalibur RS-230 Deluxe Remote Start System]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is probably to work "backwards" from the [Installation Instructions](https://www.caralarm.com/Content/Manuals/RS-230-DP_393_English.pdf), but it sounds like what you're looking for is the "Constant power input" wire on the main harness:

> **Red & Red/White Wires - Constant Power (+) In**
>
> **REQUIRED** These wires provide the constant positive 12v power supply for the
> system’s operation. CONNECTION: Connect these to a constant +12 volt supply
> with sufficient amperage for remote starting. The +12v supply to the ignition switch is ideal. Some vehicle’s have low amperage ignition switches in which case you would
> need to find a power supply at a fuse block or at the vehicle’s battery. Fuse these
> wires within 6 inches of the connection to the vehicle. The two 30AMP fuses in the
> harness protect the system module, NOT THE VEHICLE. Their use is REQUIRED.
> It is ideal to have a separate supply for each wire but, if the chosen supply is sufficient enough, you can combine both wires at the same point.

And from reading that it sounds as though disabling the device (and cutting it off from it's power source) may well be as simple as removing the fuses from this connection.